# What is the difference between pod and container memory in Lens / Openlens?

Tags: kubernetes

In Openlens, there are two graph results for memory in a pod:
(ie: when you select a pod, the graphs show up on the right panel)

1. Pod memory
2. Container memory (which excludes the networking thumbnail)

Why are they different, considering ***there is only 1 container in the pod***?
Is there a command that imitates this first pod memory graph?

**Details:**
"Pod memory"
The Pod memory graph display 4.9B
[Pod memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn9jl.png)

"Container memory"
The container memory graph displays about half 2.5G
[Container memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PObT6.png)

**What I have tried:**
I can duplicate the results of the Container memory graph with kubectl commands, or by logging into the node:
`kubectl top pod <POD>`
`cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.current`
`kubectl top pod <POD> -n <NS>`
`kubectl top pod <POD> -n <NS> --containers`

So I understand the second graph.  I can't explain the first graph (pod memory) that is near 5G.

Comment: there are things like networking, and volumes that are pod specific, but I can't imagine them taking this amount of memory